# Bad image quality when capturing a UIView with UIGraphicsImageRenderer class

Tags: swift, uiview, uiimage, screen-capture

I am currently using this very popular approach in order to **capture a view** for the user to share it or save it to his photo gallery:

```
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: self.viewToCapture.bounds.size.width, height: self.viewToCapture.bounds.size.height))

let image = renderer.image { ctx in
        self.viewToCapture.drawHierarchy(in: self.viewToCapture.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

But the thing is that the result of this is very unsatisfying because the **image resolution of the image is not very good.** Until now, I have not found another way to do it. The renderer does not have any property (or at least I know of none) that could adjust the rendered images quality.

So, I'm looking for either a **modification** to the way shown above or maybe **another way to capture a view** and have a perfectly sharp image as result. Would be glad if you could share your knowledge about that problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not related to your question but why not simply `UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: viewToCapture.bounds.size)`

Comment: @LeoDabus you are, of course, right. I initialized a local CGSize because I was experimenting with different values.

Comment: Did you get any solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

I use this extension to create an Image from a view 
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns a reference to the current graphics context. It doesn't create one. This is important to remember because if you view it in that light, you see that it doesn't need a size parameter because the current context is just the size the graphics context was created with.

```
  extension UIView {
        func toImage() -> UIImage? {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

            drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            return image
        }
    }
```

Comment: Still does not work, starting to think this is a problem that just appears when using it in a UIDocumentInteractionController...

Comment: can you share your code, on how you are using it with UIDocumentInteractionController

Comment: I can preclude that already, if you save the image directly without document controller the result is still as blurry as before...